# My dataframe contains a time column with 'W' and 'S' differentiating 'Summer' and 'Winter'. how to convert this without losing any data?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

Here is my data looks like:
[image]

when I convert this column into DateTime without specifying format using, I get random picks with NaT.
[image]

if I specify the format as format="%Y-%m-%d %HW%M:%S,%f" I get only Winter dates, and with the format as format="%Y-%m-%d %HS%M:%S,%f" I get only summer dates converted.

Is there is any way to I can get all the data gets converted to DateTime format without any NaT's?

Comment: use a "or"  condition and specify both formats as you have mentioned in this format="%Y-%m-%d %HW%M:%S,%f". Also, put your sample data in a format so that anyone can copy it and work on it.

Comment: `df['updtime'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df['updtime']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'))`

Answer (score 1):

One solution it to replace the character W ans S with empty and do the formatting.

```
df['updtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['updtime'].replace(to_replace ='[W|S]', value = '', regex = True), format='%Y-%m-%d %H%M:%S,%f')
```